# How to append json data into dataframe and update its value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to append json data to dataframe by looking at whether it does have common key or not, if yes, I want to do value update. So far, I used `jsonlite::fromJSON()` to get R list from raw json data, can add json data as new row there is no match with dataframe. I am wondering how am I gonna add value from json data if it has common key with dataframe. Any way to do this task in R?

**reproducible example**

here is the output of `jsonlite::fromJSON(jsondata)`:

```
mylist = list(version = 0L, subject = "Subject 102", organization = "HOSP", 
    time = "2018-02-10T09:30:00Z", features = list(age = 81L, 
        gender = "M", il6 = list(value = 200L, time = "2018-02-10T09:30:00Z"), 
        pct = list(value = 1234L, time = "2018-02-10T09:30:00Z"), 
        crp = list(value = 1004L, time = "2018-02-10T09:30:00Z")))
```

here is dataframe:

```
mydf = structure(list(subject= c('Subject 100', 'Subject 101','Subject 102','Subject 103'), taken_time = c(15L, 5L, 39L, -21L), il6= c(203.2893857, 
4.858269406, 4.858269406, 14220), pct = c(732.074484, 25.67901235, 
119.0221384, 120.0477168), crp = c(196115424.7, 1073624.455, 
4092823.885, 1457496.474), age = c(52L, 74L, 81L, 67L), gender = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), inpatient_readmission_time_rtd = c(79.78819444, 
57.59068053, 57.59068053, 57.59068053), infection_flag = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), temperature_value = c(98.9, 98.9, 98, 101.3), heartrate_value = c(106, 
61, 78, 91), pH_result_time_rta = c(11, 85.50402145, 85.50402145, 
85.50402145), gcst_value = c(15, 15, 15, 14.63769293)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**current attempt**:

based on @akrun suggestion, here is what I tried:

```
unlist(mylist) %>% setNames(str_remove(names(.), 'features\\.')) %>% 
  as.list %>% as_tibble %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  bind_rows(mydf, .) %>% select(-contains(c(".time", "version", "organization", "taken_time"))) %>% as.data.frame()
```

but I still can't able to add value in json data to dataframe by finding common key such as `person_id`, `crp`, `pct`, `il6`, then I just want to do value update. How can I do that easily in R? any idea?

I think using `dplyr` can do this manipulation, but I don't know how to get going from above attempt. any idea?

**desired output**:

this is the desired output that I want to get:

```
structure(list(person_id = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Subject 100", 
"Subject 101", "Subject 102", "Subject 103"), class = "factor"), 
    taken_time = c(15L, 5L, 39L, -21L), il6 = c(203.2893857, 
    4.858269406, 200, 14220), pct = c(732.074484, 25.67901235, 
    1234, 120.0477168), crp = c(196115424.7, 1073624.455, 1004, 
    1457496.474), age = c(52L, 74L, 81L, 67L), gender = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), inpatient_readmission_time_rtd = c(79.78819444, 
    57.59068053, 57.59068053, 57.59068053), infection_flag = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L), temperature_value = c(98.9, 98.9, 98, 101.3), 
    heartrate_value = c(106L, 61L, 78L, 91L), pH_result_time_rta = c(11, 
    85.50402145, 85.50402145, 85.50402145), gcst_value = c(15, 
    15, 15, 14.63769293)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

how can I get above desired dataframe? Is there any way to achieve this by using `dplyr` utilities? thanks

**update: R sessioninfo**:

here is the output of R sessioninfo:

```
> > sessionInfo() R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
> 18362)
> 
> Matrix products: default
> 
> Random number generation:  RNG:     Mersenne-Twister   Normal: 
> Inversion   Sample:  Rounding    locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United
> States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    [3]
> LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
> 
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
> 
> other attached packages: [1] stringr_1.4.0   ranger_0.12.1  
> dplyr_0.8.5     caret_6.0-86    ggplot2_3.3.0   lattice_0.20-38 [7]
> jsonlite_1.6.1 
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.3          
> pillar_1.4.3         compiler_3.6.0       gower_0.2.1         
> plyr_1.8.6            [6] iterators_1.0.12     class_7.3-15        
> tools_3.6.0          rpart_4.1-15         ipred_0.9-9          [11]
> lubridate_1.7.4      lifecycle_0.2.0      tibble_2.1.3        
> nlme_3.1-139         gtable_0.3.0         [16] pkgconfig_2.0.3     
> rlang_0.4.5          Matrix_1.2-17        foreach_1.5.0       
> rstudioapi_0.11      [21] prodlim_2019.11.13   withr_2.1.2         
> pROC_1.16.2          generics_0.0.2       recipes_0.1.10       [26]
> stats4_3.6.0         nnet_7.3-12          grid_3.6.0          
> tidyselect_1.0.0     data.table_1.12.8    [31] glue_1.3.2          
> R6_2.4.1             survival_2.44-1.1    lava_1.6.7          
> reshape2_1.4.3       [36] purrr_0.3.3          magrittr_1.5        
> ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 splines_3.6.0        scales_1.1.0         [41]
> codetools_0.2-16     MASS_7.3-51.4        assertthat_0.2.1    
> timeDate_3043.102    colorspace_1.4-1     [46] stringi_1.4.6       
> munsell_0.5.0        crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: I may have to update to your version to check the issue

Comment: Can you also include the packages version you used i.e. `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @akrun thanks, I just pasted my r session info above.

Comment: My R versioin is `R 3.6.2` and dplyr is the devel version

Comment: @akrun how can I add json data to dataframe if common key is found such as same `person_id`, `crp`, `pct`, `il6`? Is that doable? I think I am gonna try `R 3.6.2`. Now I don't know how can I get going for value update? thanks akrun !

Comment: option as in the solution is to convert to data.frame or tiibble and then use bind_rows.  One of the difficulties is the behaviour change in different versions.  Now, the latest R version is R 4.0.0.  Also, can you test with `stream_in` from jsonlite

Comment: @akrun I can't do `stream_in` because I don't have connection `con`. If we ignore R version, how to we tackle value update issue? Do you mind post possible solution which can yield above desired output? thanks a lot

Comment: can you try with `stream_in(textConnection(..`

Comment: @akrun yes, I tried but I got argument error. Here is [gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/832ba9e5ab908191b4c54dc1d38114e0) where I tried what you said to me. Thanks akrun !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213882/discussion-between-kim-and-akrun).

Comment: can you try `library(data.table); un1 <- unlist(mylist);names(un1) <- str_remove(names(un1),  'features\\.');rbindlist(list(mydf, type.convert(as.list(un1))), fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to update.  `unlist` the 'mylist', change the `type` of the elements, replace the `names` of the 'un1' by removing the prefix 'features.', create two vector of column names that are similar with the 'mydf' ('nm1') and different ('nm2').  Update the 'mydf' by joining `on` the 'subject' and assigning (`:=`) the values from the 'un1'

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
un1 <- type.convert(as.list(unlist(mylist)), as.is = TRUE)
names(un1) <- str_remove(names(un1), 'features\\.')
nm1 <- setdiff(intersect(names(mydf), names(un1)), 'subject')
nm2 <- setdiff(names(un1), names(mydf))
setDT(mydf)[as.data.table(un1), (nm1) := mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), on = .(subject)]
mydf[as.data.table(un1), (nm2) := mget(nm2), on = .(subject)]
mydf
#       subject taken_time          il6       pct       crp age gender inpatient_readmission_time_rtd
#1: Subject 100         15   203.289386 732.07448 196115425  52      M                       79.78819
#2: Subject 101          5     4.858269  25.67901   1073624  74      M                       57.59068
#3: Subject 102         39     4.858269 119.02214   4092824  81      M                       57.59068
#4: Subject 103        -21 14220.000000 120.04772   1457496  67      F                       57.59068
#   infection_flag temperature_value heartrate_value pH_result_time_rta gcst_value version organization
#1:              0              98.9             106           11.00000   15.00000      NA         <NA>
#2:              0              98.9              61           85.50402   15.00000      NA         <NA>
#3:              1              98.0              78           85.50402   15.00000       0         HOSP
#4:              1             101.3              91           85.50402   14.63769      NA         <NA>
#                   time il6.value             il6.time pct.value             pct.time crp.value
#1:                 <NA>        NA                 <NA>        NA                 <NA>        NA
#2:                 <NA>        NA                 <NA>        NA                 <NA>        NA
#3: 2018-02-10T09:30:00Z       200 2018-02-10T09:30:00Z      1234 2018-02-10T09:30:00Z      1004
#4:                 <NA>        NA                 <NA>        NA                 <NA>        NA
#               crp.time
#1:                 <NA>
#2:                 <NA>
#3: 2018-02-10T09:30:00Z
#4:                 <NA>
```